# How to Update in realm in android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have RealmObject class in which status column is there now I want to Update that status column value 
I don't know how to do this even though I Check Realm Official blog but didn't help to much.

```
public void storeDevice() {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Login.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    }
    if (telephonyManager != null) {
        Log.e("imeino", telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
    }

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wInfo = null;
    if (wifiManager != null) {
        wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    }
    String macAddress = "02:00:00:00:00:00";
    try {
        if (wInfo != null) {
            macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
        }
        Log.e("device_mac", macAddress);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    mobile = edit_mobile.getText().toString().trim();
    imei_no = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    brand = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    device_model = Build.MODEL;
    mac = macAddress;
    device_version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            DeviceModel deviceModel = realm.createObject(DeviceModel.class);
            RealmResults<DeviceModel> deviceModels =    realm.where(DeviceModel.class).equalTo("imei_no", imei_no).findAll();
            deviceModels.deleteAllFromRealm();

            deviceModel.setMobile(mobile);
            deviceModel.setImei_no(imei_no);
            deviceModel.setStatus("1");
            deviceModel.setBg_device_brand(brand);
            deviceModel.setDevice_mac(mac);
            deviceModel.setBg_device_model(device_model);

        }
    });
}
```

Here I want to Update Value in OnResponse method inside if block

```
private void storeCustomerData(Map<String, String> map, HashMap<String, Integer> map1) {

            Call<JsonElement> call = apiInterface.customerData(map, map1);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                    JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                    Log.i("jsonElement", "data");
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    String status = jsonObject.getAsJsonPrimitive("Status").toString();
                    Log.i("status", status);
                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                RealmResults<DeviceModel> results = realm.where(DeviceModel.class).equalTo("mobile", realm_mobile).findAll();
                                results.setValue("status", "5");
                                deviceModel.getStatus();
                                Log.i("status",deviceModel.getStatus());
                            }
                        });

                        Toast.makeText(RequiredData.this, "Your Data Has Been Succesfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RequiredData.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RequiredData.this, "Sorry, Unsucess to Save Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) and search for "insertOrUpdate". You must define primary key to use insertOrUpdate. Primary key would be "imei_no" in your situation.

For instance this is my UserInfo object class.

```
public class UserInfo extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String userId;
private String userAge;
private String userSex;

public UserInfo() {

}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}


public String getUserAge() {
    return userAge;
}

public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
    this.userAge = userAge;
}

public String getUserSex() {
    return userSex;
}

public void setUserSex(String userSex) {
    this.userSex = userSex;
}
```

}

And insert or update an UserInfo object like below:

```
mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

if (!mRealm.isInTransaction()) {
   mRealm.beginTransaction();
}

UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
userInfo.setUserId("135455");
userInfo.setUserAge("22");
userInfo.setUserSex("male");

mRealm.insertOrUpdate(userInfo);
mRealm.commitTransaction();
```

Comment: bro can you explain with an example